# Local Nexus Maven repository for common java libraries

Tags: maven, maven-3, dependency-management, nexus, sonatype

We have a Nexus install that has a collection of commonly used java dependencies (commons-codec, jodatime etc.)

The directory structure is similar to the below

```
commonjavalibraries
|
|_ commons-codec
| |_commons-codec
|   |_1.2
|_ commons-compress
  |_commons-compress
    |_1.3
```

I am in the process of adding the latest version of these dependencies to the repository.

To do this I have created a new pom and setup dependency management to deploy to Nexus.

However I now know that the groupId:artifactId:version attributes of the pom dictate how the project is deployed to nexus. Which I think would mean I'd need a separate pom for each group element.

How is the central repository pom managed? I realise it's possible to proxy the central repository, unfortunately our network doesn't allow downloading of jar's hence the need for a hosted commonjavalibraries repository in the first place.

Is there a way of doing what I'm trying to achieve without creating a pom for each group element?

Comment: Can't you ask your IT department to whitelist a set of URLs that the nexus server is allowed to connect to? So you can just set it up as a proxy, otherwise, you are going to have _a lot_ of work deploying all these dependendies.

Comment: Well it's not exactly a clone of central, but there are still a lot of dependencies. Also defence industry so no not really :(

Comment: I think I will never understand how paranoid some people can be. What is the difference, in terms of security, between a)  _whitelist `commons-codec`on Maven Central for Nexus_ → _let Nexus download it automatically_ and b) _whitelist `commons-codec`on Maven Central for a downloader_ → _download it manually_ → _upload it to Nexus manually. Or how else do you get those artifacts files? With an armored car directly from Apache?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a bit more digging I noticed that when dependencies were downloaded from central they were stored in `.m2/repositories` along with their pom files.

I wrote a Python script to copy these into another location and then walk that directory tree and run `mvn deploy:deploy-file` for each jar/pom pair I came across.